# Proving that $xe^{-kx}$ does converge to zero in $[0,\infty)$ without using derivatives.

Tags: real-analysis

I want to know how to bound $f_{k}(x)=xe^{-kx}$ in order to prove this function sequence converges to zero.

The method, that I have learned, is to look for the maxima of this functions using derivative criteria. However, I find that a little lame. Is there any argument for bypass derivatives and bound the functions?

I have tried this

\begin{align*}
 xe^{-kx}=\ln(e^{x})(e^{-x})^{k}=\frac{\ln b}{b^{k}}
\end{align*}

and clearly $\left(\frac{1}{b}\right)^{k}$ converges to zero since $b>1$ for $x>0$. Then I can argument from here as if I were proving for this number sequence. Is this a good argument? And, how about proving it converges uniformly?

Comment: Here you assume $k \gt 0$, right?

Comment: $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and, yes, I try to show the limit when $k\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: If you want to check convergence for each fixed $x$, and variyng $k$, $f_k(x) = a b^k$, which is clearly decreasing if $b = e^{-x} <1$. I don't understand the need to use derivatives.

Comment: "However, I find that a little lame." Really?

Comment: Derivatives are used for finding the maxima of $f_{k}$ and proving that the associated sequence of maxima (in this case suprema) goes to zero. In other terms you are proving that $\abs{f_{k}-0}\leq\sup{f_{k}}<\epsilon$ for $k\geq K_{\epsilon}$ with arbitrary $\epsilon>0$. Therefore you prove uniform convergence. What I'm trying is to prove this, without that lame argument that uses derivatives.

Comment: @elessartelkontar Why do you think the argument is lame? What do you want to use?

Comment: I think is like killing a pest using a nuclear bomb... Derivatives are a way too far sophisticated tool for this one. May be that method is faster than what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $x \geq 0$ $$e^x \geq 1 + x$$ and therefore for $k \geq 1$ $$e^{kx} \geq 1 + kx.$$ So $$x e^{-kx} \leq \frac{x}{1+kx} < \frac{1 + kx}{k(1+kx)} = \frac{1}{k}.$$

Answer (score 1):

To show pointwise convergence you can use the inequality
$$
e^{-kx} \leq \frac{1}{(1 + x)^k}, 
$$
which is derived from the inequality $e^x \leq 1+x$.

I'm not sure how to easily prove uniform convergence without using derivatives though.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for each fixed $x$, $e^{-x}=y<1$, so $xy^k\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$. Now, consider the interval $[0,\infty]$ in the extended reals. Set $f_k(\infty)=0$. We know $[0,\infty]$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$, which is compact, and $\gamma:[0,1]\to [0,\infty]$ with $\gamma(t)=-\log t$ is an homeomorphism. Note that $f_k\circ \gamma (t)=-\log t\cdot t^k$. This is a monotone sequence of continuous functions that goes to $0$, which is continuous. By Dini's theorem, $f_k\circ \gamma \to 0$ uniformly, so $f_k\to 0$ uniformly.

You can use Dini's Theorem directly on $[0,M]$ by choosing $M$ large enough and argue convergence is uniform both on $[0,M]$ and $[M,\infty]$.

Comment: Super! I haven't thought about Dini's theorem. It sounds really good!

Comment: @elessartelkontar So, you think Dini is "super" but derivatives are "too sophisticated"? If derivatives are a nuclear bomb, Dini is probably an H-bomb here. But I guess that is what you'd want.

Comment: Also, this only works if you give $[0,\infty]$ the Alexandroff 1-point compactification topology...

Comment: In fact, yes. For Dini's theorem proof you doesn't need any derivatives, only compactness and continuity in metric spaces. For me, it is intended that although you already know about derivatives, in an analysis course doesn't use derivatives at all before talking about them in that context. That's another reason for derivatives being lame here: I feel as I'm doing cheat.Using Dini's is ok, because I have already proven that in course context.

Comment: @Guillermo Yes, neighborhoods of $\infty$ are $(a,\infty)\cup\{\infty\}$.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really gotten around the underlying issue here.  In order to show that $f_k(x)=xe^{-kx}\to0$ uniformly, or to show that $g_k(b)=\frac{\ln b}{b^k}\to0$ uniformly, you need to show that $f_k$ (or $g_k$) has a bound on $[0,\infty)$ that depends on $k$.

---

The standard way to find that bound would be as follows:

Using derivatives, we find that $0 \leq f_k(x)\leq M(k)=\frac{1}{ek}$ for all $x\in[0,\infty)$. Since $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{ek}=0$, $f_k\to0$ uniformly.

Is there a (possibly weaker) upper bound than $M(k)$ we can find on $f_k$ without using calculus? Possibly.  This is still probably the simplest solution, though.